# Heroku create command clarification

Tags: heroku, heroku-cli

Is there a difference between these two commands ?

```
% heroku create
```

and:

```
% heroku apps:create
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`heroku create` [is an alias of `heroku apps:create`](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli-commands#heroku-apps-create-app):

```
EXAMPLES
  $ heroku apps:create
  Creating app... done, stack is heroku-22
  https://floating-dragon-42.heroku.com/ | https://git.heroku.com/floating-dragon-42.git

  # or just
  $ heroku create
```

And here's [the source](https://github.com/heroku/cli/blob/3f5e36901ddf432874f4a6099ee149370599ab41/packages/apps-v5/src/commands/apps/create.js#L200-L203), where the same command gets wired up as both `apps:create` and `create`.